# Java MySQL paginating

Tags: java, mysql, pagination

Im am trying to do pagination as efficent as possible.
Currently, i work with a database that has over 5 milion records.

I tried with LIMIT pageSize, startIndex, like this:
Select (a.id) From Article a ........LIMIT 50, 0
In here, the pageSize is 50 and startIndex = 0.

But this is only good if you don't go to deep through the pages. The solution was not to use startIndex, but only the pageSize:

Select (a.id) From Article a ........ORDER BY a.id LIMIT 50

Next page would be: 
SELECT (a.id) FROM Article a WHERE a.id > lasId ORDER BY a.id

But without the startIndex, it is only possible to go forwards, and only one step backwards.

Is there a better way to do pagination in Java and Mysql?

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the LIMIT technique is only good if you don't go too deep through the pages.  You can just keep moving through them 50 records at a time, changing the offset (aka startIndex) as you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do this:

```
int pageNum = ?;
int pageLength = 50;

String query = String.format(
    "SELECT ... LIMIT %d, %d",
    pageNum * pageLength,
    pageLength
);
```